# Deploying Master Target Server Azure

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to setup environment to migrate a linux AWS instance from AWS to Azure. I've successfully deployed configuration server, however Master target deployment keeps failing with clueless message:

```
Error Failed to create master target 'xxxxxxxxx'
```

Is there any prerequisite to setup Master Target Server after successfully deploying configuration server?

[job info status image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5FU6.png)

Comment: Did you check this guide from Azure? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/seamlessly-migrate-your-application-from-aws-to-azure-in-4-simple-steps/

Comment: That's what i have been following. I'll try to do it again. Thanks

Comment: Ok. I've found a problem. My core quota has been exhausted.